# How to use scrypt to produce a 256-bit key?

Tags: android, encryption, hash, cryptography, scrypt

I'm using scrypt to produce key derivation, but the problem is the output is bigger than 256bit and I want to use it in AES-GCM with 256 bit key. So how can I do that? I'm tying to make an application on Android.

Edit : 
I'm sorry guys for not giving you more information 
Okay .. the library that i'm using is this 
https://github.com/wg/scrypt

this is the out put that i'm getting

"$s0$e0801$eX8cPtmLjKSrZBJszHIuZA==$vapd0u4tYVdOXOlcIkFmrOEIr1Ml2Ue1l2+FVOJgbcI="

this is over than the AES engin can handle so how can i use it

Comment: Please show us the part of your code where you perform the scrypt derivation.

Comment: AFAIK scrypt supports arbitrary length outputs via its PBKDF2 based final step.

Comment: In addition to Duncan's comment, please also edit into the question the scrypt library that you are using. Voted down until enough information is provided for us to answer the question.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Right: "dkLen: Intended output length in octets of the derived key; a positive integer less than or equal to (2^32 - 1) * hLen where hLen is 32." from the [source](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-josefsson-scrypt-kdf-02) which seems a relatively new draft from IETF (interesting that they took that step after all that time). So the question becomes: why is the output bigger than 256 bits...

Comment: Okay i added more details .. sorry

Comment: Good, now we can answer :), changed downvote into upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Scrypt is a **key derivation** algorithm. That means you can use it to generate an arbitrary number of psuedo-random bytes.

In the wg library, the way to do that is to call the [**Scrypt.scrypt** function](https://github.com/wg/scrypt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lambdaworks/crypto/SCrypt.java):

```
byte[] key = Scrypt.scrypt(password, salt, N, r, p, 32);
```

This will give you your desired **32** bytes of key material.

### Key derivation vs Password storage

Your confusion understandable. The documentation of [wg/scrypt](https://github.com/wg/scrypt) doesn't mention the **real** use of scrypt. They only document its use a a password storage algorithm.

That is why you were mistakenly calling **ScryptUtil.scrypt** (rather than **Scrypt.scrypt**):

```
string hash = ScryptUtil.scrypt(password, N, r, p);
```

That method returns a string, which is **not** suitable a key for AES (or any other kind of) encryption.